# Checking on hidden class with jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup, hidden

I am trying to extract a line from a html file for checking purposes...
The problematic line is this:

```
<div class="cli_product_message x-hidden hidden" style="display: none;"> </div>
```

It shows in 2 different ways in different html pages, the way shown above or like this

```
<div class="cli_product_message" </div>
```

I want to do a simple thing, when there is the "hidden" class or the "style" attribute a method should return false, otherwise true.

I've tried using jsoup to parse this html using

```
select("div.cli_product_message").attr("class")
```

Then I want to verify if the string obtained contains hidden or style, the problem is that, in both cases, the result string is

```
cli_product_message x-hidden
```

So I don't have nothing to differentiate the 2...
I've tried using other jsoup methods, for example toString() but the result is the same... What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: How do you verify that attr contains "hidden" class/style?

Comment: Do you mean how I test to see if the hidden class is part of my result? I'm using a simple contains("hidden") on my result String, but it always return false for the reason I said above... My result string is always cli_product_message x-hidden independently of the initial class I parse...

Comment: But you wrote "the result string is `cli_product_message x-hidden`", and this string **contains** hidden word, right?

Comment: The html i'm tying to parse in some lines contains "x-hidden hidden", in other lines it doesn't contain anything... When I parse the result is always the same that contains "x-hidden" independently of the original line... So I don't have a way to differentiate the two... Of course it contains x-hidden but if I check on that line it always return true and that's not what I want... I want to know why the parsing is always the same and how can I avoid it...

Comment: You can check like so: `attr.contains("hidden") && !attr.contsins("x-hidden")`

Comment: But the string I get is always the same! The problem is not in the check, it's in the parsing, the result string should be different but I get always the same... I want to know if there is a way to correctly parse that line, not a way to check it...

Comment: Of course, `select("div.cli_product_message")` will return first node that satisfies specified path. If it is the same page - it always be the same node.

Comment: In each html page there is one node that satisfies that select... I'm parsing different html pages with the 2 different values said above but the result is the same...

Comment: Then you should show full code in your question.

Comment: String s = getHtml().select("dd > div.cli_product_message").attr("class");


    System.out.println(s);


    return (s.contains("hidden")&& !s.contains("x-hidden"));


that's the method I wrote...

Comment: And what does `getHtml()`? Seems that this method returns the same page

Comment: It returns the Document I'm parsing... I'm using this method on different Document objects...

Comment: You are not showing full code. It is very hard to guess where is the problem.

Comment: I'll upload it later but the problem is not in the other code... It works fine for many other checks using the same method... I don't know how to tell you that it is just a problem of jsoup that doesn't parse the html properly...

Comment: Hmm, and what you are expecting? Method `attr` returns unexpected value? what is expected?

Comment: The attr method is provided by jsoup, I pass "class" and that should return the content between " " contained in class="cli_product..." In the original htmls there are two possible values for class... But jsoup always return the same result string which is neither one of the two possible original strings...